# Cocoa-touch - implementation files?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

In Xcode, you can view all the header files of the cocoa-touch framework, but I'm just curious to see what some of the implementations look like. Is there a way to see them? They must be on the system somewhere, right? The header doesn't do anything without the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation files are compiled into libraries (binaries) and only the header files are provided. They are your contract or entry-point into those binaries. The iPhone SDK is currently closed-sourse so you won't be able to get access to the implementation files, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to check out [this (incomplete) implementation of UIKit](http://github.com/enormego/UIKit/tree/master) for Leopard. It might give you some idea of how things work.